# Columns greater than a threshold

Tags: python, pandas, threshold

How can I retrieve the columns in which **at least once** appears a value < threshold?

For instance:

```
THRESHOLD = 0

print(df)

Col_1  Col_2  Col_3   Col_4
   1     3      5      -9
   1     3      5      -9
   1    -2      5      -9
```

print(final_df)

```
  Col_2    Col_4
     3      -9
     3      -9
    -2      -9
```

I tried with:

```
df[(df < 0).any(1)]
```

But it reports the rows, not the columns, in which at least one element < 0 appears.

Comment: you can transpose but it's probably not the best solution. `df.T[(df.T < 0).any(1)].T `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can issue `df.loc[:, (df < 0).any(0)]`.

```
>>> df                                                                                                                       
   Col_1  Col_2  Col_3  Col_4
0      1      3      5     -9
1      1      3      5     -9
2      1     -2      5     -9
>>>
>>> df.loc[:, (df < 0).any(0)] 
   Col_2  Col_4
0      3     -9
1      3     -9
2     -2     -9
```

Details:

`(df < 0).any(0)` will give you the columns that have a value lower than zero, because `any(0)` operates *along* the rows.

```
>>> df < 0                                                                                                                    
   Col_1  Col_2  Col_3  Col_4
0  False  False  False   True
1  False  False  False   True
2  False   True  False   True
>>>
>>> (df < 0).any(0)                                                                                                            
Col_1    False
Col_2     True
Col_3    False
Col_4     True
dtype: bool
```

Then `df.loc[:, (df < 0).any(0)]` selects all rows and the columns for which `df < 0).any(0)` is `True` by boolean indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Using `axis=0` with `.loc`

```
df.loc[:,(df < 0).any(0)]
Out[215]: 
   Col_2  Col_4
0      3     -9
1      3     -9
2     -2     -9
```

Or we using `.iloc` with `nonzero`

```
df.iloc[:,(df<0).any().nonzero()[0]]
Out[230]: 
   Col_2  Col_4
0      3     -9
1      3     -9
2     -2     -9
```